# Display Drupal taxonomy tree

Tags: drupal-7, taxonomy

I sucessfully print the whole taxonomy tree through this code
    `$voc = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load('product_sub_categories');
    $tree = taxonomy_get_tree($voc->vid,0,NULL,TRUE);
    foreach ($tree as $key => $term){
    print $term->name."</br>";
    }`
, now I want to separatly print parent and chile in order to custon theme them, because I have already a markup in which parent has separate
    `<p class="parent_class">Parent terms</p>` 
and children has separate
   `<ul class="child_class">Child terms</ul>`. 
How should I do this, can anyone there to help me?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution

```
`$tree=taxonomy_get_children(1);
foreach ($tree as $term)
{
$item[] = $term->name;
$child_term = taxonomy_get_children($term->tid);
if (!empty($child_term))  
{
print $term->name."<br>";
foreach ($child_term as $child) 
{
print $child->name."<br>";
}
}
else 
print $term->name."<br>";
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Views Tree](http://drupal.org/project/views_tree) Module.

Here is the documentation for this module 
https://www.drupal.org/node/1493366

Comment: Thanku @uzma, but I have to fetch it through api function due to some reason and I got the answer too.